# Do lies turn facts into creative works?

Tags: copyright, liability

In [the answer to an earlier question of mine](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77738/where-are-the-limits-of-creative-expression-in-graphical-data-displays), there was this statement and comment:

Answer:

> mapping companies make deliberate errors in their data such as adding streets or geographic features that don’t exist. While the data about real streets and geographic features is a fact and not subject to copyright. “Facts” about fictional things are creative works and are subject to it. So if you reverse engineer Google map’s data and create your own map, you will be in breach of copyright because your map will include the same fictional information. Gotcha!
>
> BTW, paper mapmakers did this too; including Ordinance Survey maps.

Comment:

> Apparently fictional facts also were used to protect Trivial Pursuit decks from copying.

My first thought was does that mean I can lie to a journalist, and if they print the lie I can claim copyright on there whole distribution?  Then I thought what if [ensembl](https://www.ensembl.org/) is doing this?  They could be quitely introducing [synonymous substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonymous_substitution) into the data, and then at a later date reveal the intentional inaccuracies and claim copyright over most of the biomedical field that uses their data (which could well be in the region of a trillion dollars at this point)?

I am sure they are not, not least because the data is hosted independently at the [UCSC](https://genome.ucsc.edu/).

Is this really true?  Can an organisation present data as factual, and therefore not protected by copyright, and then at a later date reveal that it contained inaccuracies so the users are in breach of copyright, and are liable for damages to the entity that introduced the inaccuracies?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is at heart a difficult philosophical one: what is a "fact"? A fact is some describable aspect of reality, and it is not the sentence used to describe reality. It is more like "an abstract logical proposition, free from language". Copyright law protects the specific expression of an idea in a language (it could be via some other symbolic means but let's avoid the complexity of a 'lying picture'). The propositions that underlie a protected work do not have to be true (therefore works of fiction are canonical examples of copyright-protected works). From a legal perspective, truth does not determine what the "fact" is, therefore you cannot claim copyright over an actually-factual work by inserting a false assertion into the work.

Your original scheme for copying involved actual copying without permission plus a transformation of the original work. When you speak to a reporter (a) you understand that the reporter will extra both "facts" and "expression" from the interview – which when it leaves your mouth is not a creative work with a fixed form and (b) you voluntarily agree to letting the reporter disseminate that content. So there is no impermissible copying, irrespective of the veracity of your claims.

The relevance of injecting fake data into an otherwise factual database is that it provides *proof* of an illegal act – copying a protected work without permission. Google Maps is clearly a "creative work", and you have provably copied (without permission) a creative work. The Fibonacci sequence is not a protected work and aside from the millenia-old mathematical insight underlying the sequence, it is not a "creative work", so you cannot be sued for copying it from a web page, even if they insert a false entry (6767).

Comment: My point about google maps was that I could take what they distribute, abstract the fact such as there a a road here, the elevation here is X, and then redistribute that data.  In much the same way as I am not infringing on ensembls code copyright when I quote a genome sequence, even though the display of that sequence on the web was a creative work.

Answer (score 1):

### Expressions of facts *are* protected by copyright

The first quote misrepresents the reality (my bad, I wrote it).

Google maps is a creative work and is fully protected by copyright. You can’t copy it, make derivative works etc. without their permission or a fair use/dealing exception.

The facts that are embedded in that creative work about the location of roads etc. are *not* protected by copyright. You can go and collect those facts (including from Google maps) and publish your own map without infringing Google’s copyright. However, if you don’t take the time to verify what parts are facts and what aren’t then you are not making an independent work based on the facts, you are making an unlawful derivative work and, one that is *provably* a copy.

### You don’t have copyright in what you *say*

Copyright only exists in literary of dramatic works that have been fixed in tangible form. Most things you say are not so fixed.

If you are reading a written speech copyright exists in the written speech, not the delivery, and belongs to the speechwriter, not the speaker. If a journalist records what you say (by recording OT in notes) then they own the copyright as they are the one who fixed it in tangible form.

Notwithstanding, a journalists use of copyright material for reporting the news is almost certainly fair use/dealing.

Comment: -1 "*However, if you don’t take the time to verify what parts are facts and what aren’t then you are not making an independent work based on the facts, you are making an unlawful derivative work and, one that i* provably a copy.*" At least in US l;aw thius is flat wrong. *Feist v Rural* is exactly on point here. One company republished the "facts" in anther's directory, including a "copyright trap"  (false entry) and did not verify them. The US Supreme Court ruled that there was no infringement of copyright. Such a collection of gacts has no originality adn no copyright at all.

Comment: "*copyright exists in the written speech, not the delivery, and belongs to the speechwriter, not the speaker*" That depends. If the speaker dictates a speech to a secretary who types  it (or writes it down), and if the secretary is an employee of the speaker, under US law the speaker will hold the copyright. If a speaker arranges for someone to make an audio recording of a speech  or take it down on paper, who holds the copyright will depend on the details of the agreement between speaker & recorder. These issues came up over the cpyrt of MLK's "I have a dream" spch. His widow now owns cpyrt.

Comment: @DavidSiegel weren't the "traps" decided as copyright infringement?

Comment: @Trish No they were not. Par 59 pf *Rural* reads: "*Because Rural's white pages lack the requisite originality, Feist's use of the listings cannot constitute infringement.*" Pat 6 mentions four "fictitious listings " but they are never refereed to again, and are **not** held to be protected.  Par 18 reads "*a subsequent compiler remains free to use the facts contained in another's publication*" Par 31 holds ther is no requirement toi independently collect facts. Nothing in the *Feist v Rural* opinion holds that purported facts, even if intentionally false, are protected.

Comment: @DavidSiegel there is substantially more creativity in a map than in a list of phone numbers.

Comment: @Dale that is true, but the location data in a map are still uncopyrightable facts, and anyone may copy them directly from the map as long as the protectable elements are not copied. There is no legal requirement to verify such data on the ground. Can you cite **any** source for such a need to verify, and if so is it a US source? I intend to look for cases on map copyrights that go beyond Feist, but the basic rule of Feist is still in place in the US, of that I am sure. There are more expressive choices possible in a map than in a phone book, or a graph but that give no protection to data.

Comment: @DavidSiegel There was a case where one company claimed another company infringed the copyright of their map by taking the specific creative choices they made in how to pack streets and street names into congested areas where they might have to abbreviate street names or use arrows. The court held that this was insufficiently creative and too driven by practical requirements and the need to produce an objectively "best" result to justify copyright protection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this really true? Can an organisation present data as factual, and therefore not protected by copyright, and then at a later date reveal that it contained inaccuracies so the users are in breach of copyright, and are liable for damages to the entity that introduced the inaccuracies?

No, that would never work in the United States. In effect, by presenting the data as factual, you have represented that you hold no copyright interest in the data that you would only hold were the data not factual. If that representation results in you having any damages, you have only yourself to blame.

This is why the use of fake streets in maps doesn't work either. You can't represent that the streets are real and then sue someone for copyright infringement when their infringement was induced by your misrepresentation.

Now you might think you can still pull this off by alerting people that your work contains *some* fictional elements. They then wouldn't want to take the risk of duplicating those fictional elements. You could try to get people to, out of an abundance of caution, not take anything from your work -- even the facts that are not protected by copyright.

But allowing this kind of abuse would allow people to get the effect of extending copyright protection to facts. Copyright protection for facts is not available specifically because such a thing would be a disastrous public policy. So US law prohibits you from creating a scheme to extend copyright to cover things not covered by the law itself. This doctrine, in the case of copyright, is called "copyright misuse".

> DGI nevertheless insists that, even assuming that it committed acts of
> copyright infringement, the "copyright misuse" doctrine precludes
> injunctive relief based on that infringement. This doctrine — which
> has its historical roots in the unclean hands defense — "bars a
> culpable plaintiff from prevailing on an action for the infringement
> of the misused copyright." It "forbids the use of the [copyright] to
> secure an exclusive right or limited monopoly not granted by the
> [Copyright] Office and which it is contrary to public policy to
> grant." -- Alcatel v. DGI, 166 F.3d 772 (Fifth Circuit, 1999)

This comes from a long line of cases that establish that one cannot claim the protection of patent or copyright when one has unclean hands, that is, when one attempted to misuse the rights granted by patent or copyright to acquire rights not available under those intellectual property regimes and that the government has specifically decided that it would be a bad idea for intellectual property owners to have.

Comment: how does this work with Feist v Rural, where the court held that only the fictional numbers were copyright infringement?

Comment: @Trish Are you talking about some lower court holding? The Supreme Court holding was "merely" that facts couldn't be copyright nor could a collection of facts unless the criteria for including the facts or the means of presenting the facts was somehow creative and original? The doctrine of copyright misuse applies to things for which one can have a valid copyright but nevertheless there is no liability for infringement because such liability would offend public policy by extending copyright to protect things it isn't supposed to protect.

Comment: @Trish I just read the entire *Feist* opinion. It contains no such holding. The lower court actions as summarized in the opinion included no such holding either. Can you quote the passage you had in mind?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I must have misremembered then. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the jurisdiction. There are many places where databases of publicly available facts *may* hold their own copyright even if individual facts would be free to use. The purpose of that law is to protect/reward the effort that went into assembling the database from public information. The problem might be in proving that someone used the database and did not re-create it from public information, and there the 'lie' matters -- it is **evidence** of the copying.

Likewise, a modern photograph of an ancient, copyright-protection-expired artwork may be copyright-protected in itself to protect/reward the effort of the photographer. Taking your own picture of the original would be legal, provided you had access to it (museums might regulate commercial photography of their art).